# How to add an image to Django's Syndication RSS-feed

Tags: django, rss

Having this model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    …
    image = StdImageField(
        upload_to="img/images",
        blank=True,
        variations={
            "large": (1024, 1024),
            "thumbnail": (150, 150, False),
            "medium": (600, 600),
        },
        delete_orphans=True,
    )
```

and this view

```
…
from django.contrib.syndication.views import Feed
…
class LatestItems(Feed):
    title = "LatestItems"
    description = "Latest Items"
    link = "/sitenews/"

    def items(self):
        return MyModel.objects.all()

    def item_title(self, item):
        return item.description_short

    def item_description(self, item):
        return item.description

    def item_link(self, item):
        return reverse('item_detail', args=[item.pk])
```

How to add an image to the body of an RSS-article?

Comment: Where do you want to add that image? on the rss feed page or as an item to each of your "MyModel" instance?

Comment: Having the RSS-Feed as an list of myModel-objects, I want to have it at each of the objects. So like every object is having a picture associated that should be printed. I was playing arround with item_description() but not very successful so far :/

Comment: @frlan Have you tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61577291/12578202)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A -- maybe not technically best -- approach that works so far for me is to define my own template. Even it's not encapslled in CDATA or using the enclosure-tag of RSS it appers to be rendered correctly in most of the RSS reader I'Ve tried -- so a clear "works for me".

```
     description_template = "feeds/latest.html"
```

The template is a normal Jinja-template, which is not uspporting full set of HTML. However, for my little project a template like

```
<h1>{{ obj.description_short}}</h1>
<img src="{{request.scheme}}://{{request.META.HTTP_HOST}}{{obj.image.medium.url}}" />
```

(Not happy with the build of URL, but this should be solveable with e.g. the idea of another answer

```
    def item_extra_kwargs(self, item):
       …
```

So my complete view looks something like this:

```
class LatestFeed(Feed):
    title = "Latest Items"
    description = "Latest Items"
    link = "/"
    description_template = "feeds/latest.html"

    def items(self):
        return myModel.objects.all()

    def item_title(self, item):
        return item.title

    def item_description(self, item):
        return item.detail

    def item_link(self, item):
        return reverse('item_detail', args=[item.pk])
```

Answer (score 5):

Create a custom **`feed_type`** and set in the **`Feed`** view,

```
from django.contrib.syndication.views import Feed
from django.utils.feedgenerator import Rss201rev2Feed
from django.conf import settings


class CustomFeed(Rss201rev2Feed):
    def add_item_elements(self, handler, item):
        super().add_item_elements(handler, item)
        handler.addQuickElement("image", item["image"])


class LatestItems(Feed):
    feed_type = CustomFeed
    title = "LatestItems"
    description = "Latest Items"
    link = "/sitenews/"

    def items(self):
        return MyModel.objects.all()

    def item_title(self, item):
        return item.description_short

    def item_description(self, item):
        return item.description

    def item_link(self, item):
        return reverse('item_detail', args=[item.pk])

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        setattr(self, 'request', kwargs['request']) # to access the request object later
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

    def item_extra_kwargs(self, item):
        img_url = item.image.url
        request_url = self.request.build_absolute_uri('/')[:-1]
        image_url_abs = f"{request_url}{settings.STATIC_URL}{img_url}"
        return {
            'image': image_url_abs
        }
```

### Result

[image: Result Screenshot]

Comment: Well... it adds the tag <image> to the output, but it's not rendered by any of the tried RSS readers. According to documentation of RSS it appears that media files either needs to go to enclosure-tag (item_enclosures() by django.contrib.syndication) or to render some HTML inside a CDATA-section

Comment: I've posted a working solution for me as another answer. However, I like the updating of context thing so I gave it at least an upvote

Comment: Great!!.. I have managed to generate a similar result, as this https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lyD1.png .

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
...

class LatestItems(Feed):
    ...

    def item_image(self, item):
        domain = 'https://example.com'
        return domain + item.image.url

...
```

Comment: This did not change anything -- also I couldn't ind item_image() at the documentation. Did I miss something?